# drawing bezier at 3d cursor draw on some plane

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-cursor

I followed [3D cursor orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146012/3d-cursor-orientation) (adapting to 3.0.1 UI) to set the 3d cursor to some surface, when I rotate/pan, looks like the 3d cursor is correctly placed (but I don't know is the Z axis is the one pointed on the surface's normal)
then

- shift+a -> curves -> bezier
- tab (enter edit)
- suppr -> vertices (erase)
- select draw tool
- set mode to 2d (but 3d do the same), fill mode full (I want to create a surface to be able to extrude it
- on top left I see "bezier" then a button "3d cursor" that is selected
- draw something on the surface (looks like drawn on the surface)
- rotate the view (the actual drawing is somewhere else in the background on some plane)

I have few questions...

1. how can I change the appearance of 3d cursor? I can't see clearly what is the Z axis (since the drawing on 2D will occurs on 3D cursor XY plane)
2. why isn't the drawing occuring on the XY plane of 3d cursor?
3. is there some shortcut to set the view in orthographic view into 3D cusor XY plane (like top/front/top/back in world referential)

thanks and regards

Comment: seems that I found... if someone can confirm
in edit -> settings -> Editing -> Objects -> new Objects -> Align to -> 3D Cursor

Comment: how to set 3d cursor to normal of underlying geometry under 3.0 : select 3d cursor tool, on top left there is a "orientation" settings that appears, select Geometry
to have the same behavior on shift+rightclick : open settings -> keymap -> search for the 3d cursor -> select the shift rigthclick entry -> modify orientation to geometry

** if you don't modify the settings for shift+rightclick, the 3D cursor Z axis will be oriented according to current view angle.... **